# javascript export reusable function

Tags: javascript

I am building this application for someone that has a lot of ajax requests. I am using the **Q** library for promise handling and I have found that a lot of my requests are exactly the same:

```
export function createAppointment(data) {
    return Q($.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/appointments',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }));
}

export function availableAppointments(data) {
    return Q($.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/appointments/available',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }));
}
```

What I would like to do is define one function that can be called that accepts the ajax options, but does the promise. I would like it to get the options as defaults which can be overriden.

For example in my case, the options there would look like this:

```
{
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}
```

The only thing I need to override is the **url**.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a function that returns a promise? I mean, what are you having a problem with, exactly? Given what you already have it seems like a trivial task. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You could have a ajax call wrapper that takes `url` and `data` as the parameters and import it. Which in turn could return promise as well, If `Q` does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to answer this myself. I have created a new javascript file called **data.js** which looks like this:

```
import Q from 'q';
import $ from 'jquery';

const defaults = {
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
};

export function httpPost(url, json) {
    const data = JSON.stringify(json);
    const options = Object.assign({}, defaults, { url, data, type: 'POST' });

    return Q($.ajax(options));
}

export function httpGet(url, data) {
    const options = Object.assign({}, defaults, { url, data, type: 'GET' });

    return Q($.ajax(options));
}
```

the in my other JavaScript files, I have done this:

```
import { httpPost, httpGet } from './data';

export function createAppointment(data) {
    return httpPost('api/appointments', data);
}

export function availableAppointments(data) {
    return httpPost('api/appointments/available', data);
}

export function listAddresses(postCode) {
    return httpGet('api/addresses', { postcode: postCode });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` to patch an object containing default values with custom ones.

Since  the URL will change each time, i've added it to the signature as a distinct parameter.

```
function performRequest(url, data, options) {
    return Q($.ajax(Object.assign(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }, 
    options, 
    {   
        url: url,
        data: data,
    }
    )));
}
```

Here, `data` and `url` will always override the content of `options`.